# pdf_load_font() function, fatal error

Tags: php, pdflib

```
<?php  
     $pdf = pdf_new();  

     pdf_open_file($pdf, "philosophy.pdf");  

     pdf_begin_page($pdf, 595, 842);  

     $arial = pdf_load_font($pdf, "Arial", "host", "embedding=true"); 
     pdf_setfont($pdf, $arial, 10);  

     pdf_show_xy($pdf, "There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio,", 50, 750); 
     pdf_show_xy($pdf, "than are dreamt of in your philosophy", 50, 730);  

     pdf_end_page($pdf);  

     pdf_close($pdf);  
?>
```

I found this code in internet, just to observe how PDFLib works. But, it gives me the error below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDFlibException' with message 'Font
>   'Arial' with encoding 'host': Font file (AFM, PFM, TTF, OTF etc.) or
>   host font not found' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pdf.php:8 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pdf.php(8): pdf_load_font(Resource id #2,
>   'Arial', 'host', 'embedding=true') #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\pdf.php on line 8

Comment: Looks like that font isn't installed.

Comment: Read the error message, it tells you what the problem is. You need a font file in one of the formats mentioned.

Comment: I have Arial font installed in my computer. And it is in TTF format

Comment: Try stracing the PHP interpreter to see where it tries to find the font. I.e. on Linux: ``strace php myscript.php``

Answer (score -1):

I think PDFLib does not look at the windows' fonts directory by default, here is the suggestion:

```
$fontdir = "C:\WINDOWS\Fonts"; 
pdf_set_parameter($pdf, "FontOutline", "arialMyName=$fontdir\arial.ttf");
$arial = PDF_findfont($pdf,"arialMyName","host",0 );
```

Then, you can set the font with pdf_setfont().